# What are some essential elements to a story beat?

Tags: creative-writing, plot

https://screenwritingbae.tumblr.com/post/133954599046/an-outline-of-whiplash-2014-please-share

I see set-up and inciting incident, but then there's call to adventure, which seems like something random that not every story beat should have, and even worse last chance to chicken out. So I was wondering if there was a web app that would let me check a list of exhaustive parts or sub parts of a story beat. Something free would be nice.

Comment: It think you're looking at it the wrong way. "Set-up", "inciting incident", "call to adventure" are [stages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hero%27s_journey#Campbell's_seventeen_stages) of a story, not [beats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(filmmaking)). Typically a stage will consist of many beats (small units of action), and not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The Hero's Journey" is not the only story type to tell.

A beat is a critical element in the story outline.

The critical element of a beat is change; something changes. There are some introductory scenes and background scenes, necessary information the audience needs to know, we can count that as something changes for the audience; expectations or new information. But even those are often presented as a "change": The movie opens on a prison; and our hero Jack is in a cell with a bag packed, a guard comes. Switch to Jack in civvies being let out the prison gate to the real world; the guard tells him "See you next year, Jack." That's a **beat**, something has changed for Jack, he's being released from prison, the audience gets an important BG point, and can guess he's a repeat offender.

Typically movie beats are either positive or negative, something good has happened for our crew, or something bad has happened. Often these alternate, but sometimes your story requires a series of bad things to push somebody to a desperation move, or a few lucky breaks where things work as they close in on the villain. You do want something of a roller coaster dynamic; ups and downs, setbacks and victories.

You can start either way; good beat or bad. Jack being released from prison is a good beat. It is tempting to write a wish-fulfillment story where everything goes right for Jack, but those get boring; the audience is entertained by Jack suffering hardships and struggling to overcome them.

Suffering, hardship and struggle are what make characters relatable and sympathetic (i.e. the audience has sympathy for them). Rocky Balboa needs to be kicked down, prove he is a kind person even though he lives in poverty. He needs to suffer and sacrifice through training, and get the living crap kicked of him in the ring -- or to the audience, who cares if a champion fighter that always wins, wins another match? Yawn.

That's what you need downbeats for; your hero fails, hardships come their way, people they love die. something changes for the worse for the hero. Overall, we want more downbeats than upbeats in the first 3/4 of the story; so we build up some credit for the closing with more upbeats than downbeats (presuming a happy ending).

But relentless downbeats may not work, it seems too dark. I would not suggest more than three in a row, and like I said, some successful writers recommend alternating. I kind of like the one-two punches, good or bad, and mixing it up.

A beat represents a change. New information (good news or bad), new events, new circumstances, new locations, a success, a failure, a realization of what some clues meant (good or bad), a windfall, an unexpected cost, a puzzle solved, a hard decision made, a duty shirked, whatever. It is a plot point.

Julie tells her parents goodnight at 10:00 PM, in her bedroom after a shower she dresses for a party and climbs out her bedroom window. That's a beat, end of scene. Two locations, living room and bedroom, maybe a time skip, but one beat, one outline element. In this case, it isn't really a change for any character but audience expectations are changed, they know something new about Julie, and this creates interest.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend against this, story beats, good beats at least, can't be said to have a fixed content. An app (equally most writing courses) will tell you that the perfect beat has to have A, B, C, D and probably E to boot but this is demonstrably untrue. In the right place a single word can move the story more than a chapter, I have read a couple of brilliant stories with one word beats and many more that use a sentence or two, I have read novels that tell less of a story than those individual beats.